# myform_validate() and myform_submit() functions not responding

Tags: forms

I have built a form from following examples on tutorials but neither the accompanying `_validate(`) nor `_submit()` functions are responding when I submit this form. This is my codes:

```
/**
*implementing foodmenu form
*/
function my_magic_foodmenu_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form = array();
    $form['choice'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Choose your meal'),
        '#options' => array(
            'ricestew' => t('Rice with Stew'),
            'ricejollof' => t('Jollof Rice'),
        ),
        '#required' => TRUE,

    );
    $form['buttons']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),

    );

    return $form;
}

/**
*Implement form validation: Foodmenu
*/
function my_magic_foodmenu_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
    krumo($form_state);
}

/**
*Implementing form submition: foodmenu
*/
function my_magic_foodmenu_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
   // krumo($form_state);
}
```

From the code above, I have implemented the `'choice'` field to be `'#required'`. The `_validate()` function responds and prints the implemented `krumo()` when I submit this form without making a choice, so there is nothing wrong with the `_validate()` code then. Why does it not respond when I just submit the  form after making a choice??

### EDIT:

I would really like to know why the default `_validate()` and `_submit()` do not work in my code, given that there is nothing apparently wrong with the code. I am not looking for alternatives. I just want to get the defaults above to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The `_validate()` actually works but it has to actually test a form field in order for it respond like I wanted.

I am working with a video tutorial made by lullabot in 2011 and the first test they did with `_validate()` was just as in the OP. Just a `krumo($form_state)` without testing any form field and `_validate()` responded perfectly. So I am guessing that the Form-API has changed some since 2011 so that you must perform a test on form field in order for `_validate()` to react. So I did:

```
function my_magic_foodmenu_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
    if($form_state['values']['choice'] == 'ricestew'){
        form_set_error('choice', 'Sorry, but we have run out of Rice with Stew');
    }
}
```

It worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

1 . You can add how many submit handler you want by using this

```
 $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_what_ever_function';
```

if you want to add a submit handler after default submit handler one callback the next callback to be called you can use this, This submit handler will be called after submit call back.

```
form['#submit'][1] = test_function;
```

To unset submit handler

submit handler

```
unset($form["actions"]['submit']);
```

2. ```
   $form['#validate'][] = 'test_validation_function'; 

   function test_validation_function($form, $form_state) {}
   ```

this function will call before submitting the result.

Add these handlers and once clear your Drupal cache

Still you face issue look in to this url for example will help you out

https://www.drupal.org/node/717740

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you're experiencing is expected and correct. If you look at the comments on [`form_execute_handlers()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_execute_handlers/7):

> Button-specific handlers are checked first. If none exist, the function falls back to form-level handlers.

You've provided a button-level handler in `$form['buttons']['submit']`, so `form_execute_handlers()` doesn't need to fall back, and the default form-level handlers won't be run.

Comment: `$form['buttons']['submit']` was not meant to be a button-level implementation. I was Just simply grouping buttons and happen to use "buttons"(plural, whereas the one you mean is singular). Besides the `_validate()` or `_submit()` was not assigned to any button-level codes. Both `_validate()` and `_submit()` are form level.

Answer (score 0):

You can always force the issue by setting the submit function explicitly

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_magic_foodmenu_form_submit';
```

This may be a silly question, but is the issue the fact that the krumo is commented out in your submit function?

Comment: The `krumo()` in `_submit()` was commented out because I was testing `_validate()` at the moment.

Comment: @okeyxyz alright, just looked at the example module and, as expected, it is using the submit handler without defining it. Have you tried just forcing the submit like I mentioned above even though you shouldn't have to?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it's still no change in the outcome: `$form['#validate'][] = 'my_magic_foodmenu_form_validate';`

Comment: try it after clear the cache. some times form is cached.